# Changing whole numbers to decimal not adding or subtracting

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi guys so i had a db set up with values for different ingredients and each value was a whole number so a mango had 2 value in the db. i decided that i actually needed to use decimal numbers instead so the mango now has 0.2 value. The problem is as soon as i changed it my addition and subtract has stopped working completely.

My live site is here: this is working with whole numbers : 
http://diet.elementalbydesign.com/bootstrap-3.3.6-dist/build.php

You can see on the right hand side inside the label under fat how it adds and subtract for the values of : 
Apple, Banana, mango , melon etc.

However like i said above in my db i changed it from whole numbers to decimals as i need it to work that way , but now i cant add or subtract like before.

in my db i have fat set to  decimal(2,1).  Most of the nutrition will look like 0.4 0.2 etc etc.

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var current_fat = 0;

     $('.searchFunction').keyup( function( event ) {
            if(event.keyCode != 8 && event.keyCode != 46) {
                var search_term = $("#search_term").val();
                if(search_term != '') {
                    $.get( 'build.php', { search_term:search_term }, function( data ) {
                    $('.result').html( data );    
                    });
                }
            }
        });


        $('.result').on('click', 'li', function( event ) {
            var result_value = $(this).text();
            $('#search_term').val(result_value);
            $('.result').html('');
        });

        $('#addButton').on('click', function( event ) {
            if($('#search_term').val() ==''){
                alert('please fill something in text box'); 
            }else{ 
                    var searchedValue = $('#search_term').val(); 
                    temp = $("#fat").text(); 
                    temp = parseInt(temp);

                   $.post( 'build.php', { 'search_term':searchedValue, 'current_fat':temp }, function(data) {

                    $('#fat').text( parseInt( $('#fat').text( ) ) + parseInt( data ) )

                    var divHolder = $('.selectedStuff');
                    $("<div>" + searchedValue + "<span data-fat='"+data+"' data-itemfat='"+data+"'>X</span></div>").css({
                                'background-color': 'yellow',
                                'width': '700px',
                                'margin-top': '10px',
                                'border-style': 'solid',
                                'border-color': '#0000ff'
                            }).appendTo(divHolder);
                   }); 
                        }
        });
                            $('.selectedStuff').on("click", 'span', function(){
                        var curr_fat = parseInt($("#fat").html()), 
                        toberemovedfat = parseInt($(this).attr('data-fat')); 
                        curr_fat = curr_fat - toberemovedfat; 
                        $("#fat").html(curr_fat); 
                        $(this).parent().remove(); 
                        });     
            });
```

Again any help on this matter would be a great help

Thanks

Comment: The `Int` in `parseInt()` means **integer**.

Comment: @Pointy ah yes i know that :0 i just was wondering what to change it to , i tried diffrent things but was not adding up properly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to switch `parseInt` to [`parseFloat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat). Int is for integers, but floats can be either whole or decimal numbers:

```
                $('#fat').text( (parseFloat( $('#fat').text( ) ) + parseFloat( data )).toFixed(2) )
```

and

```
                    toberemovedfat = parseFloat($(this).attr('data-fat'));
```

Comment: ah and everything else stays as an int?

Comment: I don't understand your comments.

Comment: @Nevershow2016 `parseFloat()` takes a string and returns a number. It handles fractional parts (digits past a decimal point).

Comment: Sorry you caan see throughout my js file i have a lot of parseInt , do i need to change evrey single one of thoses?

Comment: ah i did this before, but it was not subtracting correctly with decmail places

Comment: its weird because it works with full numbers, when it comes to decmails , it does not subtract proper

Comment: actually a better question is say i add an apple 3 times with a value of 0.4 , it goes 0.4 then 0.8 and then 1.2000000000000002 , what is the way to keep it to a 1 decmail place, so it should look like 1.2g of fat

Comment: i think that is whats causing the problem

Comment: @Nevershow2016 That's a basic known issue with floating point arithmetic. Just truncate it after a couple decimal places. (num.toFixed(2), i think).

Comment: ah yes but how do i put that in with the coed thats what i mean sorry

Comment: i did that also for the subtract one : toberemovedfat = parseFloat($(this).attr('data-fat').toFixed(2));  but that is the problem

Comment: oops hang on sorry toberemovedfat = parseFloat($(this).attr('data-fat')).toFixed(2) ;

Comment: @Nevershow2016 That should work. What's the error in the console?

Comment: Ah no , that has not worked :( in the subtract role, the adding works fine now actually, but the subtract does not

Comment: @Nevershow2016 Ah. You need to apply `toFixed()` in this line: `$("#fat").html(curr_fat.toFixed(2)); `

Comment: Have a look at the liev site just updated it with decmail points to show u

Comment: Yes just did it with that line, thank u very very much for ur help sir :) if i could hug u i would :0 x